# What is the HarmonyOS alternative for RecyclerView in android?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I want to create dynamic lists which can be scrolled on the screen. To do this in Android, we create a custom adapter extending `RecyclerView.Adapter<ListItem>`, where ListItem is a class containing the content of list items extending `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

How to make such scrollable lists in HarmonyOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls kindly refer to `ListContainer` in the HarmonyOS development document.

`ListContainer` is a component used for displaying continuous data in multiple rows. It contains a series of list items of the same type.

[Docs link](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ui-java-component-listcontainer-0000001060007847).